# C# ShowDialog Parent Form is null

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms.

The **LoadWorkstationFile** prompts the users for the id that they want to load.

The **DisplayDataForm** displays the id's data that they selected on the previous screen.

In the **DisplayDataForm** they can click on an option to load new data, which calls the LoadDataForm as a ShowDiaglog:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to save the current work file before continuing?", "Confirmation",
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
  if (answer == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
  if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
    SaveWorkFile();
  var prevworkstationid = Configuration.WorkstationId;
  var lw = new LoadWorkstationFile();
  lw.ShowDialog(this);
  if (Configuration.WorkstationId != prevworkstationid)
  {
    LoadData();
  }

}
```

As you can see, I am prompting them again with the same screen as before.

In the **LoadWorkstationFile** it has the following code:

```
  if (this.Parent == null)
  {
    var sc = new ScanCheck();
    sc.Show();
    this.Hide();
  }
```

Initial load everything is fine. When I want to load data again it it has loaded, I end up with 2 of the **LoadWorkstationFile** screens cause Parent always equals null.

Do I have the wrong idea? Should the parent be the **DisplayDataForm** when it is called with .ShowDialog ?

Thanks as usual.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should check the `Owner` instead of the `Parent`

What you're setting in the constructor of ShowDialog is the Owner property.
Which tells the form which other form "owns" it.
The parent is (as indicated by Mario) described the ownership relationship for a Control.

so you should change your code to:

```
if (this.Owner == null)
  {
    var sc = new ScanCheck();
    sc.Show();
    this.Hide();
  }
```

and it should work.

Comment: In my first glance of the msdn doc I did not find that property, but later I updated my comment ;-)

Comment: @Mario The Spoon - :) good old "RTFM". thank the gods of programming for intellitrace, intellisense, and common-sense :) 
I must admit i had to verify with Intellisense before answering even tho i used this property millions of times

Comment: @NightDweller Poor me has now a new development environment (WinWord) and has to write spcifications instead of Code... So it did not have that luxury :-(

Comment: @Mario The Spoon -  Ah,i remember that day when finished my last ATP, quit my job at a project company that did government contracts and joined a startup company that never even heard of the word "process". It has it's downsides, but it's truly liberating to do most of the specs and design in my head, where it belongs! ( :) )

Comment: :) that's what we're here for

Comment: it is worth noting that you have to pass this to `ShowDialog(this)` in order for `Owner` to be available, otherwise it will be null

Answer (score 4):

Parent is a property inherited from control which is used to describe embedding relationships ( a label has as parent the form).

I do not think it is set when using ShowDialog().

I assume that Owner is the correct property to check.

hth

Mario

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing `DisplayDataForm` as parent in `lw.ShowDialog(this)`; DisplayDataForm is the parent of LoadWorkstationFile form when calling it second time.